# ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Using Python 2.7 with scikit-learn 0.14 package. It runs well on some examples from the user guild expect the Linear Models.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\P\plot_ols.py", line 28, in <module>
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\__init__.py", line 12, in    <module>
from .base import LinearRegression
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 29, in <module>
from ..utils.sparsefuncs import mean_variance_axis0, inplace_column_scale
ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale
```

Thank you~

Comment: I get the same with scikit-learn-0.15 on Python 2.7.2 - did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 29):

I was able to fix this by going to my python folder and deleting the file:

```
python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\sparsefuncs.pyd
```

My guess is that the problem was:

1. An older version of scikit-learn implemented sparsefuncs as a windows DLL
2. The current version implements it as a python file
3. If you install a new version on top of an old version it does not delete the old DLL
4. When you try to import, Python uses the pyd in preference to the py implementation
5. But the old implementation did not include this function

This suggests that there might be bigger problems caused by installing a new version and it might be wise to delete the whole sklearn directory before reinstalling the new version.

Comment: I have a .pyc file and not .pyd and cannot fix.

Answer (score 18):

I encountered the same issue in Mac Os.

I solved it by deleting the file manually:

> rm /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.so

Comment: in ubuntu, deleting /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.so worked for me.

Comment: in Ubuntu/Anaconda, deleting `anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.so` file worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling `scikit-learn` and reinstalling it was the only option that worked for me:

```
 pip uninstall scikit-learn
 pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by :

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
```

and don't forget to rm the 'sklearn' folder in the python 'site-packages'

```
rm -rf /path/Python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/
```

then reinstall the package:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had originally installed `scikit-learn` by:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```

When none of the other solutions posted here worked, I decided to uninstall my version of `scikit-learn` and reinstall it:

```bash
pip2 install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
```

Used `pip2` because I have two versions of python, so I use `scikit-learn` in Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, this has been posted as a bug on [the official Github page](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3046), along with some additional solutions, basically suggesting the same solutions as above. Long story short: run a `make clean` to get rid of the .so file.

Answer (score 0):

same problem happened with can not import _safe_split, have a look

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41024001/importerror-cannot-import-name-safe-split`

`https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7582`

EDIT: check comment by Andreas Mueller