# Why I cannot import linear model form scikit-learn 0.16.1?

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn

I have just update my `sklearn` to version `0.16.1`. As a result, if I try to import:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .base import LinearRegression
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..utils.sparsefuncs import mean_variance_axis, inplace_column_scale
ImportError: cannot import name mean_variance_axis
```

Does anybody know what is the reason for this problem and how it can be resolved?

Comment: A similar problem and its solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750247/importerror-cannot-import-name-inplace-column-scale). Try the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved by the following steps:

1. Uninstalling scikit-learn.
2. Manually delete `sklearn` directory in the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` directory.
3. `pip install` the newest version of the scikit-learn.

However, I got another problem by doing that (`Illegal instruction (core dumped)`). More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440426/why-does-scikit-learn-cause-core-dumped).