# No module named 'sklearn.linear_model.base'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np

#Load the Random Forest Classifier model

filename = 'first-innings-score-lr-model'
regressor = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\XUB\Final Year Thesis\flask\app.py", line 8, in <module>
   regressor = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model.base'
```

I have following versions

- scikit-learn  0.24.1
- Python 3.9.1

Comment: Maybe try importing the module first?

Comment: First `from sklearn.linear_model import base` then use `pickle.load`

Comment: @KillerToilet since I have scikit-learn installed it already has a sklearn so it says requirement satisfied

Comment: @Sadegh it shows following error ImportError: cannot import name 'base' from 'sklearn.linear_model' (D:\XUB\Final Year Thesis\flask\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\__init__.py)

Comment: use this answer [link](http://https://stackoverflow.com/a/30440486/10853876). I think this will work

Comment: @Sadegh please post the link correctly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30440486/10853876  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438696/why-i-cannot-import-linear-model-form-scikit-learn-0-16-1

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

Changing `.base` to `._base` solved the problem in my case.

**Somewhat Long Answer**

I also faced the same problem while working using a python library. In that library, the authors imported `_preprocess_data()` using the following statement.

```
from sklearn.linear_model.base import _preprocess_data
```

However, that generated the same issue.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model.base'

Then, changing the import statement by the following line solved the problem.

```
from sklearn.linear_model._base import _preprocess_data
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I simply opened the `.pkl` file with `notepad++`. There it was written `sklearn.linear_model.base`. Simply deleted the word `.base` and saved it as is.

Then the code runs properly.

Answer (score 1):

run **pip install scikit-learn** this will probably solve your problem