# sklearn 0.17.1: ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale

Tags: python-2.7, model, scikit-learn, importerror

My sklearn works well before, after installing and updating a couple of other packages, I cannot import any model from sklearn.

The versions:

> Python 2.7.12
>   Anaconda 2.4.1 (x86_64)
>   sklearn: 0.17.1 (downgrade from 0.18) 
>   spicy: 0.18.1

Measures I've tried:

> 1. restart the shell---> same error
> 2. uninstall sklearn, and reinstall it (the newest version is 0.18), downgrade it to 0.17--> same error
> 3. install sklearn and keep the version 0.18 -->still error

My code:

```
from sklearn import svm
```

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-fe795c4388c4>", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn import svm

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC, \

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import _fit_liblinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import LabelEncoder

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .data import Binarizer

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ..utils.sparsefuncs import (inplace_column_scale,

ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale
```

Besides svm, when I import tree, linear_model, the same thing happens.

```
from sklearn.models import linear_model
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-540f6792b379>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.models import linear_model

ImportError: No module named models
```

Code:

```
from sklearn import tree
```

error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-fcc6e7d2ee3e>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import tree

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..feature_selection.from_model import _LearntSelectorMixin

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .univariate_selection import chi2

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .data import Binarizer

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ..utils.sparsefuncs import (inplace_column_scale,

ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this within your terminal:

```
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn=0.18.1
```

If it does not work go to your terminal and try:

```
conda update anaconda
```

After the update is complete, then try the first bit of code again
Hopefully it works

Comment: The sklearn works, somehow I cannot run spyder due to version conflict...ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/libQtGui.4.8.7.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libQtGui.4.dylib requires version 39.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 34.0.0

Comment: Try this in your terminal: conda update spyder @LinZhu

Comment: Please dont forget to mark the above solution for sklearn correct ! Thanks @LinZhu

Comment: Thank you! I tried: conda update libpng, it works! I mainly because version is out dated!

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'OrdinalEnconder' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' 
    (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py)
```

You need to go path "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing"  and check the name of OneLabelEncoder in python file `__init__.py` . The name may be LabelEncoder or a different name.  You need import the module with same name.

The following screenshot should help you understand this better:

[image]

Comment: Is this answer , could you please provide exact one

Comment: Please share more details, and don't hide it in a screenshot. Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Answer (score 0):

please see this question. 
[ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750247/importerror-cannot-import-name-inplace-column-scale).

I think you face the same problem. There are several ways to solve it.

1. For **windows.** delete python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\sparsefuncs.pyd.

   For **mac and linux**, delete /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.so.

   If you use **anaconda**, delete anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/sparsefun‌​cs.so
2. reinstall the sklearn. 
   pip uninstall scikit-learn
   pip install scikit-learn